# How to get two separate result with single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

my goal is to get the sum of the points of each person and return the username and his/her total points.

```
id      |   username  |   points

1           Michelle       23
2           Chester        44
3           Michelle       13
4           Chester        23
5           Chester        65
6           Chester        43
7           Michelle       65
8           Chester        12
9           Michelle       54
10          Chester        76
```

Desire results

```
username   |  total_points

Chester    |  total points of Chester
Michelle   |  total points of Michelle
```

Comment: GROUP BY username, SUM the points, remove ID from the query.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT      username, SUM(points) total_points
FROM        mytable
GROUP BY    username
ORDER BY    username
```